# Wicket calling js based on condition

Tags: javascript, wicket

I am trying to solve the following problem, off course unsuccessfully.

On my website I have form with DataTextField where user put date.

When user confirms (AjaxButton) the form I need to find out the date and if the date is from "future" I need to call javascript(confirmation dialog).

The question is How to call js when condition is done?
I am helpless and appraise some help.

Comment: Please show the snippets from your code

Answer (score 0):

Without any code fragments it's hard to tell you what goes wrong but basically:

```
onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target)
{

target.appendJavaScript("if(confirm('Date in future!')){}; return;");

}
```